# Cache google map for offline use in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, google-maps, cache, offline

I am having an hybrid application where I am showing google map as base map with the help of Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant plugin in leaflet.

Now I need to cache the browsed base map tiles and show in offline mode. I have gone through few offline plugins from leaflet but they are compatible with TileLayer and the base map url (mostly OSM map). Please suggest some ways to cache google base map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's terms of service restrict you from caching Google Map tiles:

> No Caching. Customer will not cache Google Maps Content except as
>   expressly permitted under the Maps Service Specific Terms.

See [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms).

Comment: Even Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant is not legal, see recent https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352494/why-google-maps-is-not-popular-with-tech-stack-like-leaflet-openlayers-nebula

Comment: Thanks for the response ! Does that mean we can not cache google map tile in any way ? I believe when the tile gets rendered at client side then may be there would be some way to store the rendered tile. Please suggest.

Comment: @TomazicM AFAIK, GoogleMutant is legal and complies with Google's ToS - it's OK to use G's basemaps with your own data (as long as it's through their JS API as GoogleMutant does), but it's against their ToS to use their data with any other basemaps. Since GoogleMutant needs some of G's JS libraries loaded with an API key, it's safe to assume that the end user has read and accepted G's ToS. user684805: it's technically feasible, but since it goes against the ToS I highly doubt you'll find anyone willing to help. If you wanna get in trouble, get yourself in trouble and not others.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @IvanSanchez .. Thanks for your inputs ! I meant to ask if there is a way or method to use leaflet base map in offline mode for the already browsed part. Currently we are using google base map. However we may opt any other satellite base map if google ToS does not allow to do so .. Can you please suggest.